# inline-block appearing wider in Firefox/Safari than Chrome, spilling over line

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I made [this site](http://www.pieboyclothing.co.uk/). On Chrome (v24.0), everything appears as intended. When I look at it in Safari or Firefox, the layout breaks: the links "view cart" and "checkout" in the top right spill over to an extra line. It's hard to describe, but compare how they look in Chrome (correct) vs Firefox and Safari (wrong) and it should be obvious what I mean.

How can I fix this? Everything I've tried that successfully solves the problem in Firefox and Safari just breaks it in Chrome.

My current CSS (Sass):

```
.account-links {
    font-size: 0;
}

.account-links a {

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 90px;

    margin: 0px;
    font-size:9pt;

    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear,
                                 left top, left bottom,
                                 color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9),
                                 color-stop(1, #e9e9e9) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top,
                                     #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#e9e9e9');
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    border-top:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    &:first-child {
      border-right:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    }
    display:inline-block;
    color:#666666;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    &:hover {
      background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e9e9e9), color-stop(1, #f9f9f9) );
      background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100% );
      filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e9e9e9', endColorstr='#f9f9f9');
      background-color:#e9e9e9;
    }
    &:active {
   position:relative;
      top:1px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're using unprefixed `box-sizing` for `#shop-meta .account-links a`. Add `-moz-box-sizing: border-box` <strike>and `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box`</strike> and it should work as intended.

Edit: Actually I've found that there's some bug in Safari (using v5.1.7 for Windows) that prevents box-sizing from working properly. The solution for that browser is to set `float: left` on `.account-links a`. You don't need `-webkit-box-sizing`.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into issues with this a few times with Chrome. Most of the time I can figure it out  but a few times I've had to resort to using this: [css_browser_selector.js](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/)

Basically it allows you to write css like this:

```
.gecko .account-links a{}
```

Which would then apply that css to browsers using the gecko engine (i.e. Firefox). I use it on several production sites, (mostly for IE but once or twice for Firefox as well) and I haven't had any issues with it.

Which means that you can use your solutions for Firefox and Safari without breaking what's working in Chrome.